# How to you scale, move or rotate outside blender window

Tags: customization, scale

Trying to figure out how you can continue to move, scale or rotate once your cursor hits the edge of the program window.[enter link description here](https://youtu.be/8-saHiYbnLk)

Comment: https://youtu.be/8-saHiYbnLk LINK TO PROBLEM

Answer (score 2):

By default, the cursor is supposed to automatically wrap around to the other side of the screen when it goes off the edge, allowing you to continue the operation as long as you wish.  I think this behavior is controlled by the setting:

```
Preferences -> Input -> Mouse -> Continuous Grab
```

Make sure that's checked.

As an alternative, once you reach the edge of the view window, you can press and hold down Shift (to switch to fine adjustments) and move your cursor back to the other side of the window.  Then, release Shift and continue your operation.  Note that Shift must be pressed while the cursor is still within the view window, or it may not register.

Comment: Awesome, Thank You! i don't know how it got turned off but was very annoying and is a hard question to google